# Returning a character array from a function prints garbage values but prints fine in the function?

Tags: c, arrays, function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char *generate(char a[],int s,int e,char r[])
{
    if(s>e){
        printf("%s\n ",r); //Prints the correct value "rempD" here
        return r;
    }
    int i,asci[128]={0};
    for(i=s;i<=e;i++)
        if(asci[a[i]]==1)
            break;
        else
            asci[a[i]]=1;
    char t[i-s];
    t[i-s]='\0';
    for(i=i-1;i>=s;i--)
        t[i-s]=a[i];
    if(r==0||strlen(t)>strlen(r))
        return generate(a,s+1,e,t);
    else
        return generate(a,s+1,e,r);

}
int main()
{
    char a[]="prrempD";
    printf("Largest unique string:\n%s",generate(a,0,strlen(a)-1,NULL)); // But prints a garbage value here
}
```

This function is used to return the largest unique substring within the string.
When the character array is returned, it returns a garbage value.

Comment: `char t[i-s];  t[i-s]='\0';` is bad.  Likely want `char t[i-s+1];  t[i-s]='\0';`.

Answer (score 3):

`char t[i-s];` was allocated on the stack and gets deallocated when you return from `generate()`.

If you want it to live beyond the call to `generate()` you must use the heap or some other allocation method.

Answer (score 0):

It basically boils down to returning a pointer to a local variable.

`generate` will return its fourth argument `r`, which, following the call `generate(a,s+1,e,t)`, means you're returning a local variable. As soon as you leave the function, the contents of this local variable are invalid. You need to either pass in a buffer to copy the result to, or allocate a copy (via `malloc` or otherwise) and return that pointer instead.